# Natural Logarithm contradiction?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

Please help with this contradiction.

- $e^{i\pi}=-1$
- $e^{i2\pi}=1$
- $\ln(1)=i2\pi$
- $0=i2\pi$

Comment: Please help me edit

Answer (score 2):

The complex logarithm is multi-valued.

$$e^{i2\pi}=1\leftrightarrow i2\pi=\log1+i2k\pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

Bill says "I am the son of Ted Clark".  John says "I am the son of Ted Clark".  DNA testing shows they are both correct.

Therefore:  Bill = John.

Where's the contradiction?

...

Son(Ted CLark) = John.

Ted Clark  = Father(Bill)

so

Son(Ted Clark) = Son(Father(Bill)) = Bill

But Son(Ted Clark) = John.

====

With complex numbers $e^z$ is not injective (one to one) so it is possible for $e^z = e^w$ but $w \ne z$.  There is nothing at all contradictory about that at all.

So an inverse function of $e^x$ is not definable as single value/unlimited range function.

A similar "paradox" would be:

So $\arcsin ( \frac {\sqrt 2}2) = \arcsin (\frac {\sqrt 2} 2)$

$\arcsin (\sin \frac {3\pi}4)  = \arcsin (\sin \frac {\pi}4)$

$\frac {3\pi} 4 = \frac {\pi} 4$.

In the case of $\arcsin $ the definition is *not* "$\arcsin x$ is the $\theta$ so that $\sin \theta = x$".  The definition is "$\arcsin x$ is the $\theta$ *WITHIN* $-\frac {\pi}2 < \theta \le \frac {\pi} 2$ so that $\sin \theta = x$.

So $\arcsin (\sin \theta) = \theta$ and $\arcsin (\sin \frac {3\pi} 4) = \frac {3\pi}4$ is simply not true at all.

(Another example of this is the definition of $\sqrt{}$.  The definition is not $\sqrt{x} = y$ so that $y^2 = x$.  It is $\sqrt{x} = y$ so that $y \ge 0; y^2 = x$.... assuming we are talking about real numbers.  SO $\sqrt {(-2)^2} \ne -2$.)

Now... We do something slightly different with natural log.

If $e^z = 1$ then there are an infinite set of values of complex numbers that $z$ could be.  We could have $z = 0$ but we could also have $z = 2\pi i$ or $z \in \{2k\pi i|k\in \mathbb Z\}$.

We choose to define $\ln$ not be one representative value chosen from the set (which is what we do four $\sqrt{}$ or $\arcsin$) but to define $\ln$ as a "multi-valued" function. That is a function with more than just a single output for a single input.  Ln $1$ is *any* of the values of $z \in \{2k\pi i|k\in \mathbb Z\}$.

Comment: Why is it that complex logarithms are bijective? Is it because we are continuing their domain beyond its initial definition? Is that an example of analytic continuation?

Comment: They are *not* bijective.